# How can I show that a "function" assigns exactly one value to each x in its specified domain?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions

I am teaching myself using a book, [Mathematical Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470107960), authored by Bernd S. W. Schröder. In Exercise 1-30 (b) (i) at page 16, it says that

Function $f:Q\rightarrow \tilde{R}$ is described in some detail as follows. For $n\in N$, let $f(1)=\tilde{1}$, and once $f(n)$ is defined let $f(n+1)=f(n)\tilde{+}\tilde{1}$.  Also, let $f(-n)=\tilde{-}\tilde{n}$.  For $n\in Z$ and $d\in N$ let $f(\frac{n}{d})=\frac{\tilde{n}}{\tilde{d}}$.

Then, the problem asks me to:

Prove that for all $x\in Q$ the above function is not self-contradictory by proving that it assigns exactly one value to each $x\in Q$.

I wonder how I could show that a "function" assigns exactly one value to each element in the specified domain. The problem appears to show that the function is a valid function. I do not have a clue how I try to attack this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to show that the function is [well-defined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-define). Since elements of $\mathbb Q$ can be represented in more than one way, it might be the case that your function gives different outputs depending on the representative you choose. For instance, the function
$f(a/b)=a+b$ is not well-defined. (Do you see why?)

To show your function is well-defined, you need to assume that $a/b=c/d$ and conclude that $f(a/b)=f(c/d)$ by using properties of the function $f$.

Comment: Thank you! I see your point.